# Matrix factorization inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, operator-theory, normed-spaces, operator-algebras

How does one show that the following matrix factorization inequality holds in $M_{n} (\mathcal{A})^{+}$,

$$(a_{i}^{*}a^{*}aa_{j}) \leq ||a^{*}a|| \cdot (a_{i}^{*}a_{j})$$

**Notation.** Let $M_{n} (\mathcal{A})$ denote the space of $n \times n$ matrices with entries from $\mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is an *unital* C*-algebra. Let $M_{n} (\mathcal{A})^{+} \subset M_{n} (\mathcal{A})$ denote the positive elements in $M_{n} (\mathcal{A})$.

I am using Vern Paulsen's text *Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras*, and have been stuck on proving the aforementioned inequality for an embarrassing amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every positive element $a$ one has $a\leq\Vert a\Vert I$